# Add new column to WooCommerce admin products list with discount percentage on sale products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, product

I am trying to display the percentage discount of simple products that are on sale in an additional column in the backend.

I have used the code below

```php
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_columns', 'discount_column', 20 );
function discount_column( $col_th ) {
    return wp_parse_args( array( 'discount' => 'Discount' ), $col_th );
 
}
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'discount_col' );
function discount_col( $column_id ) {

    if( $column_id  == 'discount' )
      $saleprice = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_sale_price', true );
      $regularprice = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true );
      
      if ($saleprice > 0) {
        $discountperc = ($regularprice -$saleprice) /$regularprice * 100;
        echo (round($discountperc,2)). '%';
      }     
}
```

---

But I am getting multiple (same) errors:

`Undefined variable: saleprice`

Can someone walk me through how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 06/21:** now also works for variable products.

It is not necessary to get the postmeta data via `get_post_meta` because you can access the product object via the `$postid`.

Once you have the product object, you have access to all kinds of product information.

- [WooCommerce: Get Product Info (ID, SKU, $) From $product Object](http://WooCommerce:%20Get%20Product%20Info%20(ID,%20SKU,%20$)%20From%20$product%20Object)

So you get:

```php
// Column header
function filter_manage_edit_product_columns( $columns ) {
    // Add column
    $columns['discount'] = __( 'Discount', 'woocommerce' );

    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_columns', 'filter_manage_edit_product_columns', 10, 1 );

// Column content
function action_manage_product_posts_custom_column( $column, $postid ) {
    // Compare
    if ( $column == 'discount' ) {
        // Get product object
        $product = wc_get_product( $postid );
        
        // Is a WC product 
        if ( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
            // Product is on sale
            if ( $product->is_on_sale() ) {
                // Output
                echo '<ul>';
                
                // Simple products
                if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) {
                    // Get regular price
                    $regular_price = $product->get_regular_price();
                    
                    // Get sale price
                    $sale_price = $product->get_sale_price();

                    // Calculate discount percentage
                    $discount_percentage = ( ( $sale_price - $regular_price ) / $regular_price ) * 100;
                    
                    // Output
                    echo '<li>' . abs( number_format( $discount_percentage, 2, '.', '') ) . '%' . '</li>';
                // Variable products
                }  elseif ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
                    foreach( $product->get_visible_children() as $variation_id ) {
                        // Get product
                        $variation = wc_get_product( $variation_id );
                        
                        // Get regular price
                        $regular_price = $variation->get_regular_price();
                        
                        // Get sale price
                        $sale_price = $variation->get_sale_price();
                        
                        // NOT empty
                        if ( ! empty ( $sale_price ) ) {
                            // Get name
                            $name = $variation->get_name();
                            
                            // Calculate discount percentage
                            $discount_percentage = ( ( $sale_price - $regular_price ) / $regular_price ) * 100;
                            
                            // Output
                            echo '<li>' . $name . '</li>';
                            echo '<li>' . abs( number_format( $discount_percentage, 2, '.', '') ) . '%' . '</li>';
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                // Output
                echo '</ul>';
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'action_manage_product_posts_custom_column', 10, 2 );
```